# Multi-threaded performance testing MS SQL server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Let's assume the following situation:

1. I have a database server that uses 4 core CPU;
2. My machine has 2 core CPU;
3. Assume they are of equal speed in terms of GHZ;
4. Systems are connected over a network (two lines 200mb/s each);

Test tool that I use provides # of threads parameter and will issue commands in parallel to the server.

QUESTIONS:

1. How would you test parallel reads/writes via stored procedure? Please brainstorm as any advice is appreciated;
2. How can I prove that many threads are executing the queries on the server (or should I not pay attention to this as this servers and DB's responsibility)?
3. What controls how many threads are executed at any time primarily in case of SQL server? I checked the "server properties" > processors > # of processors and threads section - waht more should I check?
4. How can I check that my application truly executes on all my machine cores - in other words - uses real threads instead of virtual ones? Or should I pay attention only to the virtual ones?
5. Should I pay attention to the network bandwidth? Can it be a bottleneck (I dont' send any big data, only commands with variables).

Comment: SQL Server is generally I/O bound, not CPU bound. If you're testing for performance, concentrate on I/O

Comment: @ElectricLlama thank you for the response. I guess what I really would like to do it to check whether as I increase the thread count that call a stored procedure on my machine - the same happens on the SQL server side. Can I be confident that this happens in development environment if it does on my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1.) not sure perhaps someone else can answer
- 2.) SQL Sentry allows you to monitor your SQL activity (use the free trial and buy if you like it)
- 3.) Max Dop controls the number of processors & also the cost threshold will affect parrallelism
- 4.) Same as 2 perhaps, i'm not sure i understand
- 5.) Depends on what you are doing are where you see aproblem SQL sentry will show wait stats that may help